# Delegate issues using GameKitHelper - cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm probably over-thinking this, but I've been stuck on it a while, so I figured I'd reach out for some advice/help.

I'm using GameKitHelper (http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/tag/gamekithelper/), thus far, it's been pretty helpful. So, I have the helper initialized on in my "MainMenu" with the protocol implemented, etc:

```
@interface MainMenu : CCLayer <GameKitHelperProtocol> {
    ...
    GameKitHelper *gkHelper;
}
```

In the main menu code, I have this:

```
    gkHelper = [GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper];
    gkHelper.delegate = self;
    [gkHelper authenticateLocalPlayer];
```

Seems pretty strait forward. In fact, it works, exactly as I expect it to. I have the methods it's looking to be in place there (even though most don't have code associated with them (yet?)). My issue is when I actually want to start my game. So, I'm using the onMatchFound() to start the game, which basically works:

```
-(void) onMatchFound:(GKMatch*)match
{    
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.2f scene: [[MultiplayerLoading initWithData:Multiplayer withMultiplayerType:gameTypeToPlay andInitiator:false] scene]]];

}
```

My issue is when I'm attempting to play the game, the receive delete method fires in the MainMenu NOT the game class, so things aren't being calculated properly.
Is there a way to pass the control to the game layer from the main menu when the onMatchFound fires?

Hopefully this gives enough info, let me know if not.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways you can make this work. One way is to have a global Singleton class as the GameKitHelper delegate. You can then relay messages via this Singleton class.

Or simply assign the new scene as the GameKitHelper delegate:

```
-(void) onMatchFound:(GKMatch*)match
{   
    CCScene* newScene = [MyNewScene scene];
    [GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper].delegate = newScene;
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:newScene];
}
```

---

Also, there seems to be something wrong with how you create the new scene:

```
[[MultiplayerLoading initWithData:Multiplayer
              withMultiplayerType:gameTypeToPlay 
                     andInitiator:false] scene];
```

It appears you are first calling the init method, then the class method `scene` which allocates the instance (see the scene implementation). It looks to me like it should rather be:

```
[[[MultiplayerLoading alloc] initWithData:Multiplayer 
                      withMultiplayerType:gameTypeToPlay 
                             andInitiator:false] autorelease];
```

Btw, the [Cocoa Coding Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html) recommend not to "link" method parameters with the "and" keyword and using "with" more than once is also quite odd. Cleaned up it should rather be:

```
[[[MultiplayerLoading alloc] initWithData:Multiplayer 
                          multiplayerType:gameTypeToPlay 
                                initiator:false] autorelease];
```

Excuse me for being picky. :)

Comment: I appreciate people being picky with my code! I'll try these changes and report back! Thanks!

Comment: OK, so I changed it to how you said, but now when receiving data in the class (MultiplayerLoading) it crashes with: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[MultiplayerLoading onReceivedData:fromPlayer:]: unrecognized selector sent to class
It attempts to receive a packet before starting play, but it crashes at this point...Thoughts?

Comment: It appears you need to implement the @selector the error message tells you to.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because your MainMenu is set as the delegate in your GameKitHelper? I'd try setting the delegate to the game inside `onMatchFound`. Give that a try.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not really finding a way to NOT have the main menu as the delegate. When the match is made, the match initiator is all fired up and works fine, but the if the person who gets the invite is NOT in the game already, the delegate doesn't attach, so they're basically useless. When you get the invite, it brings you into the game, but if the delegate is not on the main menu, it just sits there, since it doesn't have the onMatchFound stuff to fire.